# Harmonic map into $S^n \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

Consider a harmonic map $\Phi : \Sigma \to S^n \times \mathbb{R}$, where $\Sigma$ is a surface, and the metric on $S^n \times \mathbb{R}$ is given by the product metric. Choose local spherical (polar) coordinates $\omega_1,..,\omega_n$ on $S^n$ (coming from embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$) in the usual way. I am trying to see what local coordinate equations would be satisfied by the coordinates $r$ and $\omega_i$. Thanks for your help.

Note: Moved here from MO, please post answers here.

Comment: First do it using a particular choice of local coordinates on $S^n$, where you can write the metric and Christoffel symbols explicitly. Use them to derive the equation. Use stereographic projection to write the equation in terms of the map written as a map from $\Sigma$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$.

Comment: It seems that $\Phi=(\Phi_1, \Phi_2) $ is harmonic if and only if both $\Phi_1, \Phi_2$ are harmonic. So $\Phi_2$ will satisfy the Laplace equation. For $\Phi_1$, this is a harmonic maps into spheres and if $\Phi_1 = (f_1, \cdots, f_{n+1})$ (think of $\mathbb S^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$), then $\Delta_\Sigma f_i + |D\Phi_1|^2 f_i = 0$ for $i=1, 2, \cdots, n+1$.

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks for the comment. Could you please explain how you get the factor $|D\Phi_1|^2f_i$?

Comment: That is derived from a general results: If $N \subset \mathbb R^K$ is isometrically embedded and $F = (f_1, \cdots, f_K) : M\to N$ is a harmonic maps, then it satisfies $\Delta_M F + g^{\alpha\beta} A_N (\partial _\alpha F, \partial _\beta F) = 0$, where $A_N$ is the second fundamental form. I think this formula can be found in any books on harmonic maps theory.